Copy formatting of one worksheet range to a different workbook
I have the below VBA ('File' after the Workbooks.Open is a file path and has been removed for privacy reasons) and want to copy the formatting of a range in the workbook.sheet "Data". I am getting the error in the line of .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats - Error 'Object Required'.
The table in workbook CDwb, sheet "Data" has a header in row 1 where the headers are green and this wants to be formatted to be the same in the new sheet "Data Transfer" in the workbook Temwb.
Sub Data_Transfer()

    Dim CDwb As Workbook
    Dim CDws As Worksheet
    Dim Temwb As Workbook
    Dim Temws As Worksheet
    Dim Paste As String
    
    'Open Closed workbook (Collections Data)
    Set CDwb = Workbooks.Open("File\Collections Data.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True, UpdateLinks:=False)
    Set CDws = CDwb.Sheets("Data")
    Set Temws = getT.Sheets("Data Transfer")
    
    'Clear cells in Temnpate Collections workbook
    Temws.Cells.ClearContents
    
    'Transfer Data
    Paste = "A1:" & getLastColumnName(CDws, 1) & getLastrow(CDws, "A")
    Temws.Range(Paste).Value = CDws.Range(Paste).Value
    
    Temws.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
    CDws.Range("A1:" & getLastColumnName(CDws, 1) & getLastrow(CDws, "A")).Copy
    Thisworkbooks.Sheets("Data transfer").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Close Workbook (Collections Data)
    'CDwb.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub

I originally had the code below which just pasted the headers formatting into the active cell of workbook CDwb (Collections Data) and not pasting into workbook Temwb
Sub RemoveAnnualLeave()
  CDws.Range("A1:" & getLastColumnName(CDws, 1) & getLastrow(CDws, "A")).Copy
  ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub


Thisworkbooks is wrong (there is no s at the end). Either Thisworkbook or Temws

getT isn't declared anywhere.  Also, rather than using getLastColumnName - which I guess is a function that returns the column letter you can use something like Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(20,2)) which would create a reference to A1:B20 - remembering to fully qualify Range & Cells with the workbook and worksheet reference.

Use Option Explicit to catch these errors. Ref: https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html

Copy and Paste Formats and Values

Use Option Explicit at the top of each module to detect typos at compile time.

Option Explicit

Sub ImportDataCollections()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const SRC_FOLDER_PATH As String = _
        "C:\Test\" ' must have trailing path separator
    Const SRC_FILE_NAME As String = "Collections Data.xlsx"
    
    ' Source (Collections Data Workbook)
    Dim sFilePath As String: sFilePath = SRC_FOLDER_PATH & SRC_FILE_NAME
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open( _
        Filename:=sFilePath, ReadOnly:=True, UpdateLinks:=False)
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Sheets("Data")
    Dim srg As Range:
    With sws.UsedRange
        Set srg = sws.Range("A1", .Cells(.Cells.CountLarge))
    End With
    
    ' Destination (Temnpate Collections Workbook)
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Sheets("Data Transfer")
    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = dws.Range("A1")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Clear the destination worksheet.
    dws.UsedRange.Clear
    
    ' Import 1 (long)
'    srg.Copy
'    dcell.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths ' copy column widths
'    dcell.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats ' copy formats
'    Application.CutCopyMode = False ' clear the clipboard
'    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dcell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count)
'    drg.Value = srg.Value ' copy values
    
    ' Import 2 (short)
    srg.Copy
    dcell.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths ' copy column widths
    Application.CutCopyMode = False ' clear the clipboard
    srg.Copy Destination:=dcell ' copy formats and values
    
    ' Import 3 (efficient)
    ' If you insist on autofitting columns rather than copying column widths,
    ' use the more efficient:
'    srg.Copy Destination:=dcell ' copy formats and values
'    dcell.Resize(, srg.Columns.Count).EntireColumn.AutoFit
    ' Then you can optionally use 'Application.Goto dcell'
    ' because the selection wasn't affected.
    
    ' Note that at this point 'dcell.Select' would raise
    ' "Run-time error '1004': Select method of Range class failed"
    ' because the source workbook is still active
    ' but 'Application.Goto dcell' will work.
    
    ' Close the source workbook.
    swb.Close SaveChanges:=False ' it was just read from
    
    ' Select the first destination cell
    ' since 'PasteSpecial' selects the whole copied (destination) range.
    Application.Goto dcell
    ' Note that at this point 'dcell.Select' would probably work
    ' but why take a chance when 'Application.Goto dcell' always works.
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Data collections imported.", vbInformation

End Sub

